# newlib.h: No such file or directory in ffmpeg

Tags: android, ffmpeg

I am getting this error

```
/AppData/Local/Temp/ffconf.dkWUWsGo.c:1:20: fatal error: newlib.h: No such file or directory
 #include <newlib.h>
```

while compiling for ffmpeg.

> check_cpp_condition newlib.h defined _NEWLIB_VERSION check_cpp BEGIN
>   /tmp/ffconf.dkWUWsGo.c
>       1 #include 
>       2 #if !(defined _NEWLIB_VERSION)
>       3 #error "unsatisfied condition: defined _NEWLIB_VERSION"
>       4 #endif END /tmp/ffconf.dkWUWsGo.c D:/android-ndk-r10b/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/windows/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc
>   --sysroot=D:/android-ndk-r10b/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/ -D_ISOC99_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -O3 -fpic -DANDROID -DHAVE_SYS_UIO_H=1 -Dipv6mr_interface=ipv6mr_ifindex -fasm -Wno-psabi -fno-short-enums -fno-strict-aliasing -finline-limit=300 -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -marm -march=armv7-a -march=armv7-a -std=c99 -E -o /tmp/ffconf.BMIcTDua.o /tmp/ffconf.dkWUWsGo.c C:/Users/vmewada/AppData/Local/Temp/ffconf.dkWUWsGo.c:1:20: fatal
>   error: newlib.h: No such file or directory  #include 
>                       ^ compilation terminated.

Answer (score 0):

From the path you provided, I guess the file is not present there anymore, because the *Temp* folder is used for temporary files. Probably you opened an archive (.zip, .rar, .tar, .jar), and after you closed it, the temporary files were deleted. Extract the files to a permanent directory from where you can use them.

Comment: no i have extracted files required for ffmpeg compilation.

Comment: Does the SDK, compiler, IDE, know about the location of the files? Where have you extracted them?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand from the error log you are trying to cross compile FFmpeg for Android, but I am not sure if Android NDK has a prebuilt newlib version shipped with it. You could check the corresponding `platform` directory in NDK if it has the include or library, but my assumption is that you will have to build newlib for ARM before you can do this. Btw - last time I compiled FFmpeg for Android I didn't have the issues you got - are you using a correct target? Maybe the newlib is imported because of a wrong architecture.